# Opening outgoing ports on dedicated machine

Tags: windows, security, port

I have a website where I have been working with another person on a game server listing site. It queries the game servers and shows information etc. Anyway upon talking to the creator of the script he said ports need to be open on the machine to allow the dedicated to query those game servers. I understand this. However people can run game servers on whatever port they like, so does this require me to have to, allow lots of ports to be unblocked so my machine can send a query? What risk does this pose? Sorry if this is a silly question, all comments are appreciated.

I am running on a windows server 2008 r2 dedi

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec question, but a basic networking question. Voting to migrate. Read about the difference between source and destination ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can open **one port** and send queries through it **to different destination ports** :

```
127.0.0.1:50000 > 192.0.2.1:60000
127.0.0.1:50000 > 192.0.2.2:60001
```

You have to know **which port** your programm is listenning on, **if** it uses **many ports** and **which protocol** ([TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)/[UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol))

Be sure that there is no another programm using it, only **one per port**. ([Registered ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port))

Opening ports might not be a security issue if there is no **malicious programm** on your machine which is listenning on it, be sure that your script is not one .

---

Play with `telnet` or [`hping`](http://www.hping.org/download.html) tool to understand the concept of port.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your firewall will allow all out going traffic on all ports. The ports are actually blocked on other end/destination servers, hence your server is failing to query information. Or you need to know the port numbers of those destination servers so that you can send you query on that particular port.
Unfortunately, you won't be able to query if you don't know particular port numbers. However you can use application like Zenmap(nMap) to perform port scan on destination server.